# GLControl does not exist in the namespace 'OpenTK'

Tags: monodevelop, opentk

I use OpenTK and MonoDevelop.
I use GLcontext

```
GLcontrol glControl1 = new GLControl();
```

I catch error:

```
'GLControl' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenTK'
```

I added OpenTK.dll, OpenTK.GLControl.dll, OpenTK.dll.config to my project.

Any Ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct libraries for your architecture. So for x86 make sure you have the x86 libraries. For x64 make sure you have the x64 libraries. Make sure you set the architecture for your startup project to the architecture to match the libraries using the configuration manager. On a 64bit machine it is usually set up by default as combile for 'Any CPU'. Change this to the correct platform.

This is the way I do it:
Create a new test windforms application. I want to do a 64bit application so I use the configuration manager to set my startup appliction to x64. Using NuGet install the opentk.glcontrol. It will automatically resolve OpenTK as a dependency and install it.

Here is some code adding the control and setting the background colour to skyblue:

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OpenTK.GLControl _glControl;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _glControl = new OpenTK.GLControl();
            _glControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(_glControl);

            _glControl.Load += control_Load;
            _glControl.Paint += control_Paint;

        }

        private void control_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            _glControl.SwapBuffers();
        }

        private void control_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GL.ClearColor(Color.SkyBlue);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        }
    }
}
```